# Does a second fan in the tube accelerate the flow even more?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, fan

For example, if there is a tube with a certain diameter and one fan in this tube that generates a flow of air with velocity X, will an additional fan (or several fans) accelerate the air even more? If so, how much?